# check50 expects exit code 0 not 1 in numb3rs.py

Tags: python, cs50

The problem I'm trying is cs50's introduction to programming with python problem set 7 numb3rs problem, wherein I need to check if the Ip address entered is a valid Ip address or not. The thing is check50 gives me three error messages that I do not understand. These are the three errors:

```
:( correct numb3rs.py passes all test_numb3rs.py checks
    expected exit code 0, not 1
:| test_numb3rs.py catches numb3rs.py only checking if first byte of IPv4 address is in range
    can't check until a frown turns upside down
:| test_numb3rs.py catches numb3rs.py accepting expecting five-byte IPv4 address
    can't check until a frown turns upside down
```

```py
import re

def main():

    print(validate(input("IPv4 Address: ")))

def validate(ip):
    address = "(0|[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-2][0-5][0-5]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9])"
    if re.search(fr'^{address}\.{address}\.{address}\.{address}$', ip):
        return "True"
    else:
        return "False"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This is the code. I tried using sys to exit the program after print but that does not work. I also tried returning True and False as bools but that also didn't work. I also did a test_numb3rs.py as the problem asked for it and checked everything(All bytes, if user input was not an Ip address, and so on).

Comment: Your code looks fine, and it has a 0 exit code when I run it. Make sure you named the file correctly.

Comment: Maybe try asking on [cs50.se], since your question is about using check50, not about programming.

Comment: I see, thank you very much it looks like it is a bug with check50 itself.

Comment: "The thing is check50 gives me three error messages that I do not understand" Literally all they say is that the first test failed, and it did not try to run the other tests because of that. We cannot help you understand why it failed, because it did not give any information, nor do we know what the test cases are.

Comment: Yeah, i solved it thank you. Sorry it is my first post and use of stack overflow forgot to add the test file.  I had a problem with the tests some things that check50 needed but i did not do.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

here are my codes, and i pass all the tests:

```
 import re


 def main():
   print(validate(input("IPv4 Address: ")))


 def validate(ip):

if re.search(r"^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$", ip):
    list_of_numbers = ip.split(".")
    for number in list_of_numbers:
        if int(number) < 0 or int(number) > 255:
            return False
    return True
else:
    return False



  if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

and the test_numb3rs.py:

```
  from numb3rs import validate

    def main():
     test_format()
     test_range()


  def test_format():
      assert validate(r"1.2.3.4")==True
      assert validate(r"1.2.3")==False
      assert validate(r"1.2")==False
      assert validate(r"1")==False

  def test_range():
      assert validate(r"255.255.255.255")==True
      assert validate(r"512.1.1.1")==False
      assert validate(r"1.512.1.1")==False
      assert validate(r"1.1.512.1")==False
      assert validate(r"1.1.1.512")==False



  if __name__ == "__main__":
      main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello questioner and everyone putting so much effort to solve this challenge. Thank you!

But here is my hypothesis and possible solution (after long research):

- Firstly, you should know that a valid IPv4 address consists of exactly four integers separated by single dots. Each integer is between 0 and 255 (inclusive) and cannot have leading zeros. *[Read More](http://carpentries-incubator.github.io/python-testing/06-edges/index.html#:%7E:text=the%20valid%20range.-,Edge%20Cases,at%20least%20one%20internal%20point.)*

The first time I had the error message shown was because I added an edge case to test if the user inputs what was meant to be an 'invalid' IPv4 address and return False per the line of code below

(which is also correct 'outside' check50 cause it correctly handles IP addresses with or without leading zeros in the octets, ensuring that addresses like "192.168.01.1" are considered invalid, as expected):

```
if re.search(r"^(0|[1-9]\d*)\.(0|[1-9]\d*)\.(0|[1-9]\d*)\.(0|[1-9]\d*)$", ip):
```

Then I thought maybe check50 wanted us to validate IP addresses with leading zeros because why wouldn't they let my code pass when I am trying to invalidate an 'invalid' IP address?!.

Anyway everything worked correctly per check50 requirement when I changed the line of code above. As an example:

```
import re

def main():
print(validate(input("IPv4 Address: ")))

def validate(ip):
if re.search(r"^\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+$", ip):
    split_ip = ip.split(".")
    for i in split_ip:
        if int(i) > 255:
            return False
    return True
else:
    return False

if __name__ == "__main__":
main()
```

And my test:

```
import numb3rs

def main():
    test_valid_ipv4()
    test_invalid_ipv4()

def test_valid_ipv4():
    """
    Test the validate function with valid IPv4 
    addresses.
    """
    assert numb3rs.validate("192.168.0.1") == True  # A typical private IP address
    assert numb3rs.validate("10.0.0.1") == True  # Another private IP address
    assert numb3rs.validate("0.0.0.0") == True  # The special case of the all-zeroes IP address
    assert numb3rs.validate("255.255.255.255") == True  # The maximum valid IP address
    assert numb3rs.validate("172.16.0.1") == True  # Yet another private IP address
    assert numb3rs.validate("8.8.8.8") == True  # A public DNS server IP address
    assert numb3rs.validate("192.168.01.1") == True  # Leading zeros in an octet

def test_invalid_ipv4():
    """
    Test the validate function with various 
    invalid IPv4 addresses.
    """
    assert numb3rs.validate("256.0.0.0") == False  # Out of range octet
    assert numb3rs.validate("192.168.0.256") == False  # Out of range octet
    assert numb3rs.validate("192.168..1") == False  # Missing octet
    assert numb3rs.validate("192.168.0.1.2") == False  # Extra octet
    assert numb3rs.validate("10.10.10.10.10") == False  # Five octets
    assert numb3rs.validate("2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:03 
    70:7334") == False  # An IPv6 address



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

In conclusion I had to return True (in test_numb3rs.py) and change my code (in numb3rs.py) so it doesn't invalidate an IP Address with leading zeros.

**Happy Coding!**

- Muhammad Idoniwako

Answer (score -2):

A program exit code should be 1 when OK and 0 when not ok.

In Python you can exit your program with an exit code using the command:

```
import sys
sys.exit(100)
```

So you can just add that in your code,
or update your code this way:

```
import re, sys

def validate(ip):
    address = "(0|[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-2][0-5][0-5]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9])"
    if re.search(fr'^{address}\.{address}\.{address}\.{address}$', ip):
        return True
    else:
        return False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    v =  validate(input("IPv4 Address: "))
    print(v)
    sys.exit(int(v))
```

Comment: The default exit code is 0 unless it exits due to an exception. So their code already exits with a 0 code, calling `exit(0)` explicitly won't solve it.

Comment: I tried that unfortunately, it doesn't work, I think it is a problem with check50 itself thank you anyways.

Comment: maybee you could have a try with  : return 1 or return 0 ? or print(1) / print (0) ...depending how check50 is working ... if it gets the final return value from stdout, or from the main() function ...

Comment: In the code last line : sys.exit(int(v))  and v is set to True->1 or False->0, so it calls exit(1) or exit(0) .. or sys.exit(1-int(v)) to reverse True->0 and False->1 exit code ... which is unclear in your text